# Can't call one closure from another

Tags: groovy

I am implementing a pluggable architecture based on http://fbflex.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/hot-pluggable-extensions-in-grails-adding-and-changing-your-application-behaviour-on-the-fly/.

As it turns out, one of my pluggable closures needs to invoke another closure in the same file.

However, during execution, the call from one closure to the other fails with this exception:

```
No signature of method: groovy.util.ConfigSlurper$_parse_closure5.criterion2() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap)
```

This error is not true.  There actually is a closure that takes a map.  I think the problem is with the scoping or qualifying of the closure.

```
name ="strategy1"
key ="strategy1"

criterion1 = { params ->
   params.a > params.b
}

criterion2 = { params ->
   params.a >= params.c && params.a >= params.d
}

constructWidget = { params ->
    def base = [symbol:params.sym, price:params.pr, strategy:params.strat]
    if( criterion2(base) ) {     // this is where the exception occurs
       // ...
    }
}
```

Calls to these closures work fine from outside of the "plugin."  What is the proper way to refer to the closure named criterion2 from inside of constructWidget?

Comment: What is the version of Groovy you use?

Comment: Try calling owner.criterion2(base) instead of just criterion2(base)

Comment: owner.criterion2() did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you describe is well-reproducible, when loading the plugins with the help of ConfigSlurper:

```
def plugin = new ConfigSlurper().parse( new File('plugin1.groovy').toURL() )
plugin.constructWidget([:])
```

the problem is solved by using GroovyShell instead of ConfigSlurper:

```
Binding binding = new Binding()
GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(binding)
def plugin = shell.evaluate(new File('plugin1.groovy'))
plugin.constructWidget([:])
```

**update-20140104:**

if you are loading plugins in a loop:

```
new File( grailsApplication.config.externalFiles ).eachFile { file -> 
  Binding binding = new Binding()
  GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(binding)
  shell.evaluate(file)
  strategies.put( binding.variables.key, binding.variables )
}
```

Comment: Adding def to the closure did work.  However, I found that the additional line (criterion2 = criterion2_) actually prevented that from working, which was very peculiar.  So simply adding def to the closure turns out to be the whole fix.  The downside to this, I believe, is that the closure with def is not accessible outside of the pluggable file.  Any idea why?

Comment: Are you loading your plugins with ConfigSlurper?

Comment: The problem you described is well-reproducible with ConfigSlurper and disappears as soon as ConfigSlurper is replaced with GroovyShell. No need to specially adjust your script. I'll update my solution above.

Comment: I'm calling ConfigSlurper.parse() in a loop, and I'm not sure how to convert to GroovyShell.  `  new File( grailsApplication.config.externalFiles ).eachFile{ file ->
   def config = new ConfigSlurper().parse( file.toURL() )
   strategies.put( config.key, config )
`

Comment: I have a followup question regarding logging from these scripts at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21011234/add-logging-to-an-external-pluggable-script.  Thanks for your help!